# Some entries not added in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to create a dictionary based on the keys of another dictionary.
Here's the code that I use:

```
dic2 = {}
dic1 = {'k1':'v1', 'k2':'v2', 'k3':'v3'}
for i in dic1.keys():
    for j in dic1.keys():
        print (i,j)
        dic2[i]=j
print (dic2)
```

Output :

```
k1 k1
k1 k2
k1 k3
k2 k1
k2 k2
k2 k3
k3 k1
k3 k2
k3 k3
{'k1': 'k3', 'k2': 'k3', 'k3': 'k3'}
```

Why all the entries are not added in the dictionary ?

Why don't we have :

```
dic2 ={'k1':'k1','k1':'k2','k1':'k3','k2':'k1','k2':'k2','k2':'k3','k3':'k1','k3':'k2','k3':'k3'}
```

but instead :

```
dic2 = {'k1': 'k3', 'k2': 'k3', 'k3': 'k3'}
```

Comment: Dictionaries must contain a `set` of unique keys. This is because the keys are hashed and used to lookup values. You may benefit from using a `defaultdict(list)` where you can have a single key pointing to a list of values.

Comment: @patalvali, as JacobIRR keys are unique, so what is happening is that you are seeing the last value that was assigned to each key.

Comment: Quite aside from your script here, try just typing `dic2 ={'k1':'k1','k1':'k2','k1':'k3','k2':'k1','k2':'k2','k2':'k3','k3':'k1','k3':'k2','k3':'k3'}` followed by `print(dic2)`, and see what you get...

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Makes sense. One thing that I still don't understand.  Why is it the latest entry that is kept ? It seems more logical to keep the first one (as the others could be considerated as duplicated keys). No ? another point : This question is perhaps duplicated with another one but certainly not with the one that is mentioned. (2 very different questions IMHO)

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries must contain a `set` of unique keys. This is because the keys are hashed and used to lookup values. You may benefit from using a `defaultdict` with a `list` factory, instantiated as: `defaultdict(list)` where you can have a single key pointing to a list of values.

```
from collections import defaultdict
dic2 = defaultdict(list)
dic1 = {'k1':'v1', 'k2':'v2', 'k3':'v3'}
for i in dic1.keys():
    for j in dic1.keys():
        print (i,j)
        dic2[i].append(j)
print (dic2)
```

Result:

```
{'k1': ['k1', 'k2', 'k3'],
 'k2': ['k1', 'k2', 'k3'],
 'k3': ['k1', 'k2', 'k3']}
```

Note that when we call `dic2[i].append(j)`, the `defaultdict` creates a new list for you if the current key does not yet point a list to append an item to.

If you do not want to use a `defaultdict`, you could use [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
{k: [kk for kk in dic1.keys()] for k in dic1.keys()}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary keys have to be unique. You cannot have two "k1" keys for example.
In your case, each key keep the value you assigned to it last.